# How do I define a JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, 8

In Drupal 8 some JavaScript changes were introduced: All JavaScript scripts should be defined using `hook_library_info()` and added to the page only with `#attached` attribute of the render array.

What should I do to define external libraries? Should I create a *libraries* directory and upload the library there, or should they be managed by the module using Composer?

Answer (score 3):

Since you posted this question, [hook_library_info was replaced with *.libraries.yml files](https://drupal.org/node/2201089).

An example of a simple library declaration looks like this:

```
jquery.form:
  remote: https://github.com/malsup/form
  version: 3.39
  js:
    assets/vendor/jquery-form/jquery.form.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.cookie
```

Once declared, this library can be attached to a render array like this:

```
$element['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/jquery.form';
```

Now Drupal should take care of adding the library and all required dependencies to the page. Even though the library declaration can contain a remote url, Drupal will not automatically download the library for you.

If I'm not mistaken, you will always need a module or a theme with a .libraries.yml file to act as the provider of your library. However a module can be really simple, you [only need a .info.yml file](https://drupal.org/node/2217931) to declare a module.

Comment: The last bit's not totally true, you can also [use it in a theme](https://drupal.org/node/2228783)...

Comment: Thanks Clive, you're completely right. It was so obvious to me that I forgot to mention it :-) I updated the answer.

Comment: I used this answer to draft documentation on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195