# How do I add CSS & JavaScript to <head>?

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to add the following code in my  section of the front page using a Drupal 8 sub theme of Bartik.

Can anybody help how to do it? What is the best way to do it in this new twig version of theme? Where is page.tpl?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="stepcarousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

On you THEME.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  header: true // <--- To the header!!!
  css:
    theme:
      css/mystyle.css: {} // if you want add custom css
  js:
    js/stepcarousel.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal // for use drupal.js
    - core/jquery
```

On you THEME.info.yml:

```
name: THEME
base theme: Bartik
...
libraries:
  - THEME/global-styling
...
```

and **Clear Cache**

> Where is page.tpl?

Here: core/modules/system/templates/page.html.twig

If you want use it, copy to theme folder inside templates, like this:

```
 THEME
   templates
     page.html.twig
```

Change all you want and **Clear Cache**

Answer (score 7):

In Drupal 8, [stylesheets and JavaScript files are attached as libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195):

You add a yourtheme.libraries.info to your theme (or custom module) folder:

```
power-slider:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/power-slider.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      css/power-slider.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

And then attach the library to a render array. For example, this attaches the library to all pages:

```
function yourtheme_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {
  $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'yourtheme/power-slider';
}
```

This approach has the advantage of being reusable. You define the necessary paths once and you can re-use them in different places in your code.

See:

- [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195)

*This answer was very much inspired by [berliner's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/104094/12010).*

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: Updated the links.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8 client resources like CSS and JavaScript files are attached to [render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760):

```
$element['#attached'] = array('js' => array(PATH_TO_JS));
```

Where `$element`can be an output render array or a form element.

Alternatively, you can [register a library by defining it in a *.libraries.info file](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/adding-javascript)

```
power-slider:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/power-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

and then attach the library to a render array like this:

```
$element['#attached']['library'][] = 'NAMEOFTHEMODULE/power-slider';
```

The latter approach has the advantage of being reusable. You define the necessary paths once and you can re-use them in different places in your code.

Comment: After you wrote this hook_library_info() was replaced with a *.libraries.yml file. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/109029/12010 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195

Comment: i dont think it is really outdated. it needs some editing, that is all. ill give it a try

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: @batigolix, nice edit.  However, it probably better that you post the updated answer as *your* answer, instead of changing berliner's code (code edit tend to be rejected as too intrusive).

Comment: OK, I added the updated version as a new answer. you're right: I had to change more than I thought was necessary initially.

Comment: CSS and JS files can no longer be directly attached to render arrays. Libraries are the only option now.