# Where should I store 3rd Party external js libraries?

Tags: javascript, 8

This is a follow up to [Define JavaScript library in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90609/define-javascript-library-in-drupal-8)

I have a third party library that I don't want to bundle with a module. In Drupal 7 I could just ask the user to extract to `sites/all/libraries` what is the best practice in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do it exactly like in D7. Put it in /libraries or /sites/all/libraries and use the libraries module to detect the location.

location.module itself unfortunately doesn't work that well in 8.x yet, so you have to define an 8.x-1.x library and then use the libraries API to get the location and dynamically alter. Or I guess you could also do that part yourself.

I'm doing that in the JW Player project, see [jw_player_libraries_info() + jw_player_library_info_alter()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jw_player/tree/jw_player.module?h=8.x-1.x#n102). It unfortunately still requires a bit of code, maybe that will improve in the future when libraries.module works better in 8.x.

Comment: I think this is the closest to an answer I'll find at the moment, fwiw I'm going with /libraries and will provide drush integration to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

If we follow what symfony2 uses, we have to use then: /vendor/libraryname/lib/Libraryname/src/libraryname.js